# Problem with OBIEE 11g Analysis- Dimension and Fact joins

Tags: obiee

I have created a level-based hierarchy (Logical Dimension). Created physical joins and logical joins as well. Now, when I am creating the analysis using hierarchy and some measures from the joined fact tables, it is not giving the values and when I am going further to check the physical query of the analysis, the physical query is showing only dimension not the joined fact. What could be the reason for it?

Comment: That explanation isn't detailed enough to allow any comment. Needs more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.